# Hover effect not working in android browser

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design, hover

There is a mobile layout I am working on for this website, but for some reason the hover effect for my off-canvas toggle is not working properly whenever I use a android browser to test it. The hover effect off-canvas nav links work just fine. The icon I'm using for my toggle is part of the font awesome font. I am not too sure what to do at this point. Any help will be appreciated.

**relevant html:**

```
<div class="mobile sb-slide">
       <span class="sb-toggle-left">
           <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
       </span>      
 </div>
   <div class="sb-slidebar sb-left sb-style-push">
         <nav class="slide">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="index.html" class="pink">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="about.html" class="orange">About</a></li>
                 <li><a href="contact.html" class="purple">Contact</a></li>
                 <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**relevant css:**

```
div.mobile
{
    display: none;
    background-color: #64b2f5;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99999999;
}

div.mobile span i
{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    padding: 0.4em 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.mobile span i:hover
{
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: 400ms ease;
} 

nav.slide ul
{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: right;
}

nav.slide ul li a
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.65em;
    padding: 0.45em 0.6em;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

nav.slide ul li a:hover
{
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
}

nav.slide ul li a.pink:hover
{
    background-color: #d9618f;
}

nav.slide ul li a.orange:hover
{
    background-color: #5ee9ef;
}

nav.slide ul li a.purple:hover
{
    background-color: #9648a5; 
}

@media screen and (max-width:825px)
{
   div.mobile
   {
     display: block;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hover works with mouse pointer.. and android does not have.

Answer (score 0):

Because Any Phone don't have Functionality Like Hover.

A click(TAP) will work as hover in android Browser.

I created gallery in website. In that hovering on an image shows sharing link but In Mobile it works When user TAP on the Image

Comment: I wish it were as simple as saying that, I think this is a different issue. My hover effects for nav.slide pop up when I tap on them no problem at all. It's only my off-canvas toggle's hover effect that I'm having a hard time getting to pop up.

Comment: You can Give Extra button to popup image view in mobile view